# Azure AD B2C/Captcha error at Sign Up - Error Code: AADB2C/ Message: Please Complete the Captcha/ Status: 400

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-b2c, recaptcha, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, msal.js

Sign Up users with Azure B2C and more exactly using [MSAL with Net Core/Angular](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/2-call-api-b2c). 
In the Sign Up also can be added Captcha and for the Captcha I used the following Guide which is recommended by Azure AD B2C: [Azure AD B2C with Google Captcha v2](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-node-sign-up-user-flow-captcha). 
Steps I did for adding Captcha, besides what is present in the Guide:
-case when is not possible to create an azure function app from vs code, created first from the portal
-in vs code in the Azure TAB - workspace, than press on the "+"Create a function (helps in creating a httptrigger/select Function), which will be created locally
-add the code that is present in the Guide (CaptchaAzureFunction - indexjs)
-install the required npm install axios/qs
-to see if it works, press F5
-than you can deploy it to the function app that is already created in the portal

**Issue is at Sign-Up, after completing the captcha is requesting to Complete the captcha, which was already completed.

The following error appears: "Please Complete the Captcha" (on the users page) and on the request of the SelfAsserted:

Error Code: AADB2C

Message: Please Complete the Captcha

Status: 400**

***What can I check to see where the issue comes ? Or what can I add to see for what I am looking ?***

Thank you.

**Update 1:**

After checking the logs in the portal azure function app, the message is from the function itself and it seems that when I press the create button (to create the user it's calling the api the http trigger) and in the logs appears:
2022-11-10T10:14:45.118 [Information] JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2022-11-10T10:14:45.118 [Information] value of captcha check
2022-11-10T10:14:45.119 [Information] undefined
2022-11-10T10:14:45.119 [Information] No captcha token verification code was sent to the API.
2022-11-10T10:14:45.120 [Information] Executed 'Function'
Means that is failing in the Azure Function, because the message is from the function(CaptchaAzureFunction - indexjs). Still I didn't manage to fix the issue.

**Update 2:**

Can someone help me output a part of the code, that I am not managing to see it ?
[File containing the code/index.js](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-node-sign-up-user-flow-captcha/blob/main/CaptchaAzureFunction/index.js) (please check it)
I want to see with console.log() the following objects:
-captchaToken
-captchaApiCheck

I only managed to see the object: "data" which is from the req.body and I seen what is in it using JSON.stringify(data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the issue was from B2C_EXTENSIONS_APP_ID.
In the configuration of the Function App, be careful when you add the ID, **to be like:
"B2C_EXTENSIONS_APP_ID":"02427953f9a647009a8f351234567890"**
***and not 02427953-f9a6-4700-9a8f-351234567890*** .
**Remove "-".**

Answer was received from Issue section of the [Captcha Tutorial Page](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-node-sign-up-user-flow-captcha/issues/5)

Hope it helps somebody who didn't see it like me.